# 'yet' is wrong; 'but then' is right?

Tags: grammaticality

[Source:](http://dlbin.com/ebooks/elearning-books/18416-if-i-was-you-and-alot-more-grammar-mistakes-you-might-be-making.html) p 142, *If I Was You...*, Lauren Sussman, 2014

> **Faulty coordination** occurs if you join (combine or coordinate) two clauses in an illogical way:
>
> [1.] Joey and Micah made their way to the head of the checkout line, ***yet*** Joey realized he had forgotten his wallet.
>
> The word ***yet*** (the word that joins, combines, or coordinates the
>   two clauses) is `used incorrectly`. The sentence could read:
>
> [2.] Joey and Micah made their way to the head of the checkout line, but
>   then Joey realized he had forgotten his wallet.

How and why is ***yet*** `used incorrectly` in 1? Both 1 and 2 look perfectly right to me?

Answer (score 2):

They both seem correct to you because you're assuming *but* and *yet* are interchangeable synonyms – but that is not always the case!

The difference is similar to the difference between *however* and *nevertheless*. Those two words are also interchangeable in many – but not all – instances.

If *yet* were properly used in the example sentence, it should be rephrasable to this:

> Even though Joey realized he had forgotten his wallet, Joey and Micah made their way to the head of the checkout line.

This doesn't explain the situation very well, because Joey and Micah would have made their way to the front of the line regardless of who had remembered or forgotten their money or their wallet.

Let's alter the example to a case where *yet* is used properly:

> Joey and Micah made their way to the head of the checkout line, yet neither of them had any money.

I can rephrase this as:

> Even though neither of them had any money, Joey and Micah made their way to the head of the checkout line.

This makes a little bit more sense. If I found this passage, I would assume that the author was going to explain why the two men got in line even though they didn't have any money.

The word *yet* doesn't make a good coordinating conjuction between the two men getting and waiting in line and Joey's sudden realization that he didn't have his wallet.

It's also worth noting that the corrected version doesn't use *but*, but *but then*. The *then* is a key word that makes the sentence sensible; it indicates when Joey realized his wallet was at home – after they had reached the head of the line. Without that word, neither *but* nor *yet* make apt conjunction.

By the way, it's a very subtle difference that I had to think about for some time.

Comment: Will you please to respond in your answer, and not as a comment?

Comment: Thank you. 3. What about 'yet then'? 4. Also, is the first blockquote in your answer meant to indicate a WRONG use of *yet*? You wrote `If _yet_ were properly used in the example sentence`, yet (I purposely didn't use 'but then' here since I want to know if this usage is right) you later wrote `This doesn't explain the situation very well`

Answer (score 1):

You watched carefully as I placed the white rabbit in my upturned top hat, did you not?  Long white ears. Cotton tail. Twitching pink nose. In it went. *Yet* there's nothing in my hat!  [shows the inside of the hat to Law Area 51 Proposal]

Yet = contrary to expectation