# Grammaticality: 'neither "but" nor "yet" make apt conjunction'

Tags: grammaticality, conjunctions

> [[Source:]](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/47776/8712) It's also worth noting that the corrected version doesn't use *but*, but *but then*. The *then* is a key word that makes the sentence sensible; it indicates when Joey realized his wallet was at home – after they had reached the head of the line. Without that word, neither ***but*** nor ***yet*** **make** *apt conjunction*.

1. The correlative conjunction ['neither ... nor' is singular](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/46171/8712), and ***but*** and ***yet*** here are singular subjects, so should **make** be **makeS**?

2. *apt conjunction* as the predicate looks wrong, but I can't pinpoint why. Should this be *an apt conjunction* or *apt conjunctionS* ? Why or why not?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is asking a previous answer. The user can just as easily comment on that answer and ask for clarification.

Comment: The cause of your confusion could just be a typo. Sometimes when I'm writing a longer answer and I'm trying to be clear, agreement issues creep in when I revise my thought. Is there a reason that you didn't just ask @J.R. to clarify that sentence?

Comment: @ColleenV I was thinking of that, but I didn't want to ask lengthy disparate questions (Since these questions don't relate to the OP there) in comments.

Comment: @δοῦλος Though the question was "sparked" by the content of an answer (that was likely just a typo) to another question on the site, the question (questions, actually) itself seems valid enough. I ran a search of "neither...nor" for duplicates but didn't notice one that dealt explicitly with subject-verb agreement in neither...nor constructions and/or making the subject complement singular or plural.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes, you're [correct](http://www.myenglishpages.com/site_php_files/grammar-lesson-either-or-neither-nor.php#.VNwRn1Kmrmg). The same rule that applies to *either...or* or simply *or* also applies to *neither...nor*. If the subjects are singular, the verb that follows them should also be singular: Without that word, neither *but* nor *yet* **makes** an apt conjunction. Note that in the case of mixed subjects (i.e. one singular and one plural) the verb will match the subject that is closer to it.
2. Based on the singular subjects, it should be written as ***an*** apt conjunction.

Comment: You make an important point: that the number depends on the things being disjoined: *Neither bears nor badgers have horns*.  It would not be *has* horns, because *badgers* is plural.